# Java map: multithreading juggler

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, dictionary, concurrency

I faced the next problems:

1. I have many asynchronous readers and writers. Has jdk got any implementation that provide thread safety for my case? As I understand ConcurrentHashMap isn't appropriate for situation when there are many asynch writers.
2. If I need to synchronize two concurrent maps between each other, can I achieve that without full synchronization? (I mean without adding synchonized keyword at each method)

---

I read your comments and decided to reformulate my question.

Imagine situation, you have to concurrent maps:

```
//Singleton
public class Container {
   public ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyObj> map1 = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyObj>();
   public ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyObj> map2 = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyObj>();

   public void replaceForward(String key) {
     Object value = map1.remove(key);
     map2.put(key, value);
   }

   public void replaceBackward(String key) {
     MyObj value = map2.remove(key);
     map1.put(key, value);
   }

   //This operation should be as quick as possible!
   public void replaceAllForward(int criteria) {
     for (Map.Entry<String, MyObj> entry entry : map1.entrySet()) {
       if (entry.getValue().criteria = criteria) {
         replaceForward(entry.getKey()); 
       }
     }
   }

   //This operation should be as quick as possible!
   public void replaceAllBackward(String key) {
     //just the same but from map2 to map1
   }

   public void remove(String key) {
      map1.remove(key);
   }

   public void add(String key, MyObj value) {
      map2.put(key, value);
   }

   //This operation should be as quick as possible!
   public Map<String, MyObj> getByCriteria(int criteria) {
     ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyObj> resultMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyObj>();
     for (Map.Entry<String, MyObj> entry entry : map1.entrySet()) {
       if (entry.getValue().criteria = criteria) {
         resultMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue); 
       }
     }
     return resultMap;
   }
}
```

And you have two threads, both operates with those maps.

**Thread1:** replaces elements from `map1` to `map2` (i mean removes from `map1` and puts to `map2`)

**Thread1:** replaces elements from `map2` to `map1`

***Question:*** Is it thread safe?

Comment: "*ConcurrentHAshMap isn't appropriate for situation when there are many asynch writers.*" => what makes you think that?

Comment: could you please elaborate on what you mean in 2.? What is the relationship between the maps?

Comment: @assylias I just heard that. Am I wrong?

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk ConcurrentHashMap is designed exactly for that: multiple readers and writers.

Comment: The question now is whether this is atomic or not, isn't it?

Comment: @mdrg yes, you're right

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk what you are proposing can work without using the synchronized keyword. However thread-safety is context dependent, so you are going to have to paste the code that reads and writes to the maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ConcurrentHashMap like in your example and if you write:

```
V value = map1.remove(key);
if (value != null) map2.put(key, value);
```

you have the guarantee that no item will get "lost" and no item will be added to map2 more than once, even in the presence of multipler readers/writers.

However there is going to be a short time during which the key/value will not be in map1 or map2. This may or may not be a problem for your use case.

In your `replaceAllForward` you iterate over one map and move the content to the other map. Here again, the move will happen safely, but there may be some items left in the original map at the end if they have been added in the meantime.

---

> How to make `getAllByCriteria` faster?

It depends on the size of your map. If it's small-ish, you probably can't do much better. If it is larger, you can parallelise the job.

With Java 8, you could probably get a better performance with something like:

```
public Map<String, MyObj> getByCriteria(int criteria) {
  return map1.entrySet()
      .parallelStream() //this is your speedup
      .filter(e -> e.getValue().criteria = criteria)
      .collect(toConcurrentMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
}
```

Prior to Java 8, you could write the parallel algo yourself and see if it improves the performance.

Comment: 1) do you mean that it's absolutely thread-safe? 2) How make `getAllByCriteria` faster?

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk Once again it depends on what thread safety you need. If you need to make sure that the entries are either in map1 or map2 *at all time* then no, it's not safe. If you are ok that when it's being moved, the entry is neither in map1 nor map2, then it's safe. In other words it depends on what the invariants of your class should be.

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk See my edit regarding your second question.

Comment: thanks for explanation. Not it isn't OK that entity can be neither in map1 nor in map2.  What should I do? Maybe there is a way to represent those two maps as one? (but in such case I must have a quick way to extract submap1 and submap2 from the summar map)

Comment: I don't see an obvious solution without locking... You can ask a new question around that specific problem.