# Concurrent map with multiple values for one key and auto-remove on timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary, concurrency, guava

I'm newcomer in concurrency. I read about Guava `Cache` and `MultiMap`. I look for something that can combine some possibilities of both:

1. From `Cache` I want auto-removal after ACCESS_TIMEOUT and WRITE_TIMEOUT has been expired.
2. From `Multimap` I want multiple values associated with one key.
3. All that must be concurrent.
4. I has multiple writers and multiple readers. I want to add values with rundom keys and remove them.

***Question:*** Is there map implementation that fits my needs?

**UPDATED: `Striped<Lock>` solution**

More I read about `Striped<Lock>` - more attractive that seems to me. But it arose even more questions in my head:

1. If I use something like `Striped<Lock>` with Guava `Cache` which already uses `ConcurrentHashMap` I can face the problems with deadlocks or performance decline. Am I wrong?
2. If I use  `Striped<Lock>` over `Cache` it still doesn't remove the question linked with multiple values per key.
3. Does `Striped<Lock>` eliminate the need of using concurrent map in my case? (I suppose the answer is YES) but in GitHub a saw the contrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with a `Cache<SomeKey, Collection<SomeValue>>` (so you still get the expiration) and use synchronized collections (`Collections.synchronized*()`) as the values.

But what's really the question here is the type of concurrent access you need on the collections:

- Is it enough that the operations are synchronized so the collections don't get corrupted, or do you need higher-level semantics like what `ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent()` offers?
- Do you need to do multiple operations on the collections of values in an atomic way? Like if you need to do

  ```
  if (c.contains(v)) {
      c.remove(v);
  } else {
      c.add(v);
  }
  ```

  you usually want to put that into a `synchronized(c) { }` block.

If so, you'll probably want to wrap the collection inside a class exposing those higher-level semantics and managing the lock around multiple operations to get the atomicity you need, and use that class as the value: `Cache<SomeKey, SomeValuesContainer>`.

---

As mentioned in the comments, [`Striped<Lock>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html) can be used to synchronize the access to multiple `Cache`s/`ConcurrentHashMap`s without imposing a single lock and its performance impact in case of even moderate contention.

If you need multiple `Cache`s/`ConcurrentHashMap`s, that is: why don't the `Peer`s (or a wrapper around it) actually contain that information?

### 1. Deadlocks, performance

Guava's `Cache` is similar to `ConcurrentHashMap`, but it doesn't use it. However, both work in the same way by having segments which can be locked independently, thus reducing contention when accessing the map concurrently (especially when updating). Using a `Striped<Lock>` around the access to either one cannot cause a deadlock, which only happens if you're not locking multiple locks in a consistent order: that can't happen here, as you'll always lock your `Lock` obtained from `Striped<Lock>` before calling the `Cache` or `ConcurrentHashMap`, which then locks its segment (invisible to you).

As to performance, yes, locking has a cost but it really depends on the level of contention (and that can be tuned with the [number of stripes](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html#lock%28int%29) in a `Striped<Lock>` or the [`concurrencyLevel`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#concurrencyLevel%28int%29) in a `Cache`). However, you need proper concurrency support anyway since without it you can get invalid results (or corrupt your data), so you *have* to do something (using either locking or a [lock-free algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm)).

### 2. Multiple values per key

My original answer still stands. It's difficult to get an exact idea of what you're exactly trying to do from your multiple questions (it's better if you can provide a complete, consistent context in *one* question), but I *think* you don't need more than concurrent modification of the multiple values per key so the synchronized collections should be enough (but you need **at least** that). You'll have to reason about your access patterns as you add them to make sure they still fit the model, though: make sure your [`replaceAll*()` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067533/java-map-multithreading-juggler) lock what they need, for example.

### 3. Is `ConcurrentMap` still needed with `Striped<Lock>`?

*YES!* Especially with `Striped<Lock>` vs a single `Lock`, because you'll still get concurrent updates for keys which don't use the same stripe (that's the whole point of `Striped<Lock>`) so you need data structures which support concurrent modification. If you use a simple `HashMap`, you have every chance of corrupting it under enough load (and cause infinite loops, for example).

Comment: seems I want all types of concurrent access. I've already posted the code, so hope you'll look at that (only at code) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067533/java-map-multithreading-juggler/22068934?noredirect=1#22068934. In that example I want to change ConcurrentHashMap with something I've described in my question

Comment: You don't really describe the access patterns in either this question or the other one, so it's still not clear what level of atomicity you want, especially when manipulating several `ConcurrentMap` or `Cache` at once, which adds another level of complexity. Could you complement your question with specific scenarios and the expected results in a multithreaded context: Thread1 adds this key and these values, Thread2 removes some of the values for the same key, etc.? We need to understand what should happen in each "map" as well as across those.

Comment: I think you could use a [`Striped<Lock>`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html) to avoid a global lock when moving data between the "maps", at least when the data moved is related to a single key.

Comment: Oh, and it's not clear how `MyObj` and the collection of values per key relate: do you actually need to store several `MyObj` per key, or is `MyObj` the class wrapping a collection of values I was writing about?

Comment: `MyObj` (or `Peer`) associates with user's session or to be more precise with user's tab. User can work with my application from multiple tabs, and each tab is proceeded in separate thread. BUT all those tabs have the same `sessionId`. So actually my map looks like `ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Peer>`. It can contains multiple `Peer` objects for the same `sessionId`.

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22145321/cachelong-blockingdequepeer-combined-with-stripedreadwritelock-is-it-thr please